# How to get data from a url in a https .get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, https

I'm trying to respond to input from a user, thats entered in a form, using node.js, express, and bodyParser. When I `console.log(req.body)` it prints `{}`. That would make sense if there was no data in the url, but there is. The form submits correctly `http://localhost:3000/stmd?symbol=FB`. I tried just `JSON.parse(req)` and getting what I need manually from there, but it seems that since the keys aren't strings, it can't parse it correctly. All I want to know is how to get `symbol = FB` when `app.get('/stmd' ...` is called. I'm not at all set on using bodyParser, it just seemed like the easiest way to go.

```
const https = require('https');
const buffer = require('buffer');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const express = require("express")
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on 3000");
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('connected');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.get('/stmd', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  //res.redirect('/')
})
```

here's the html form

```
 <form id="usrInput" action="/stmd" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol of Stock. Eg: FB for facebook">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only POST requests send form data as request body. With a GET request, you don't need the body parser, you can simply use the [query](http://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#req.query) property of the request:

```
app.get('/stmd', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  //res.redirect('/')
})
```

Comment: if im going to only be parsing simple `app.get(...` requests, should I just remove the body parser dependency then?

Comment: Yes, you only need it for POST requests